# Taking screenshots on Firefox and Safari (using their APIs or Canvas code)

Tags: firefox, safari, screenshot

I've been dealing with taking screenshots for Firefox and Safari browsers but I can't figure out how to do it! With Google Chrome API I can do it this way (it's pretty simple):

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, null, function (image)).....etc
```

BUT I can't find a SIMPLE way to do it on Firefox and Safari!! The only answer I got here was using the 'html2canvas' (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) BUT IT IS NOT a 100% solution in order to take EXACT screenshots of a specific webpage!! It doesn't work for me in this case!!!
Can someone help me with this issue in order to find a simple solution for Firefox and Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally used html2canvas and I found it quite efficient for taking partial or full page screenshots. But it does require you some knowledge of JavaScript and client side scripting.

If you are looking for a more easier approach , there are numerous extensions on Google Chrome webstore. 
A popular one is [Awesome Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en) which even allows you to take screenshot of entire webpage (till the scroll bar ends).

Comment: Is Awesome Screenshot source code available? (In order to take a look at it)

Comment: It merely depends on if it is open source , which I don't think it will be. However it is available for free. or you may contact its developer for further assistance.

Comment: Ohh that's a shame!! I need a small piece of code in order to take screenshots on Firefox and Safari browsers (I need to build a small-quick example for a cross-browser extension named Kango extensions), so that's why I'm looking for some source code (easier approach). I got already implemented a screenshot capture using chrome's API, but I still need something similar for Firefox and Safari!! :-(

Comment: There are open source addons available for firefox. You might need to do some digging to find the one you want.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/collections/kozaki/im%C3%B9/

Comment: Thanks dude!! I will take a look at those addons!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mozilla's chrome tools to draw some or all of the window to an image canvas:

```
var c2d = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
c2d.drawWindow(window, x, y, w, h, 'rgb(255,255,255)');
```

See [drawWindow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow()), [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/XPCOM_Interfaces).

I don't remember exactly, but that's the gist. The magic is the `.drawWindow()` method, which cannot be executed on the content side, it must be in an area with chrome privileges (like an add-on/extension).

Edit: Here's a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17956738/375399).