# How do I use the canvas drawWindow function in an addon created using the addon sdk?

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've create a Firefox addon using the [addon sdk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/). I'm trying to use the [canvas drawWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Graphics/Drawing_graphics_with_canvas#Rendering_Web_Content_Into_A_Canvas) function.

I've got the following code to use the function, where ctx refers to a canvas context, that I got with `canvas.getContext("2d")`.

```
ctx.drawWindow(window, 0, 0, 100, 200, "rgb(255,255,255)");
```

When I run this code, within a script that is attached using

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("app.js") // app.js contains the above line of code
});
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ctx.drawWindow is not a function
```

This error does not occur when I call functions like strokeRect and fillRect on the same ctx object.

The docs on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Graphics/Drawing_graphics_with_canvas#Rendering_Web_Content_Into_A_Canvas) says you need chrome privileges to use the code, so that may be issue. I would expect a different error, based on the [code](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/content/canvas/src/nsCanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp#2352) for the function.

I found out that I can chrome privileges in my addon using [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html), but what would I do next to use ctx.drawWindow?

Also, when I ran the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961636/override-firefox-insecure-warnings-with-aboutconfig), from a scratchpad on a page, rather than from an addon,  rather than a "Error: The operation is insecure", I get the same "Exception: ctx.drawWindow is not a function".

So, basically what I'm asking is, how would I go about use canvas drawWindow in addon created using the addon sdk?

**Edit:** I'm trying to do this because I need a method to access individual pixels of the rendered page. I'm hoping to draw the page to canvas, then access the pixel using [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29). If there are other methods of doing accessing individual pixels (in an Firefox addon), that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a code snippet, borrowed from the old `tab-browser` module of the SDK.  This will get you a thumbnail of the current tab without attaching to the tab itself.

```
var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
var tab = require('sdk/tabs/utils').getActiveTab(window);
var thumbnail = window.document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "canvas");
thumbnail.mozOpaque = true;
window = tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow;
thumbnail.width = Math.ceil(window.screen.availWidth / 5.75);
var aspectRatio = 0.5625; // 16:9
thumbnail.height = Math.round(thumbnail.width * aspectRatio);
var ctx = thumbnail.getContext("2d");
var snippetWidth = window.innerWidth * .6;
var scale = thumbnail.width / snippetWidth;
ctx.scale(scale, scale);
ctx.drawWindow(window, window.scrollX, window.scrollY, snippetWidth, snippetWidth * aspectRatio, "rgb(255,255,255)");
// thumbnail now represents a thumbnail of the tab
console.log(thumbnail.toDataURL());
```

From here you should be able to grab the data via `getImageData` and just ignore the scaling parts if you don't want that.

Comment: Just one quick question, what does this line, `thumbnail.mozOpaque = true;`, do?

Comment: how to do this in sdk 1.17?

Comment: updated it with the newer module locations and added a console.log to the end.