# firefox drawWindow() canvas function using the add-on sdk

Tags: firefox, canvas, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, getpixel

I've exactly the same issue : [How do I use the canvas drawWindow function in an addon created using the addon sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913911/how-do-i-use-the-canvas-drawwindow-function-in-an-addon-created-using-the-addon)

But the solution doesn't work.

If drawWindow can't be use with the firefox add-on sdk, there is an other solution to put a clicked pixel to a canvas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a privileged `canvas`

```js
var chromewin = require('sdk/windows/utils').getHiddenWindow();
var canvas = chromewin.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
                                                'canvas');
```

and work with it from `main.js`, not a content script.

Comment: It works ! thanks. There is really no solution to call this function from the content script ?

Comment: A content script runs with the permissions of the page it is attached to. So the answer is a stern no. But the content script can always ask `main.js` to do that, through the `port` mechanism.

Comment: Using directly the `hiddenWindow` is not suggested, 'cause it's global to the browser: other add-ons could mess with that. AMO reviewer will probably takes care of such code and suggest to change it to the author. Anyway, it's better replacing: `var chromewin = require('sdk/windows/utils').getHiddenWindow()` with `let { window } = require('sdk/addon/window')` then proceed to create the canvas as above. The module `addon/window` provides a hidden window for each add-on – you can still mess with that, 'cause in the current implementation they're hosted in the `hiddenWindow`, but it's less likely

Comment: @ZER0 good point, I wasn't aware of bug 565388. Still, I wonder how well this will work for Fennec on low-end devices.

Comment: @paa the bottle neck on Fennec and low-end device is related to the operations on canvas – I mean, compare to Firefox Desktop –; not how do you get a reference to a window. Especially in this case, where there is no much difference to get the hidden window and the addon window (that as I said is hosted in the `hiddenWindow`).