# drawWindow() broken with multiprocess Firefox (e10s)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm, e10s

The Firefox [`drawWindow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawWindow)-Function expects as first parameter a [XUL content-window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/contentWindow) as provided by the low-level api [tab utils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/tabs_utils).

However with the introduction of the multiprocess architecture in Firefox (codenamed electrolysis or e10s) directly accessing tabs via the low-level api is [no longer possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Multiprocess_Firefox_and_the_SDK). While there are compatibility shims available, it is explicitly stated that they do not [support plattform APIs that expect DOM objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Cross_Process_Object_Wrappers#Limitations_of_CPOWs).
On the other hand `drawWindow()` cannot be used in a content script since it is ["chrome only"](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawWindow).

So my questions are these:

1. How am I supposed to use `drawWindow()` if I cannot use it outside of chrome and cannot get a contentWindow-object within chrome?
2. What are my other options to let my addon take screenshots of websites within multiprocess Firefox?

<sub>Our current approach is based [on the answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913911/how-do-i-use-the-canvas-drawwindow-function-in-an-addon-created-using-the-addon). However it will not work with multiprocess Firefox</sub>

Comment: It will work from a framescript for sure. There is a dire need for a full page screenshots that work with frames. Even the built in firefox node screenshot tool fails at times. Here is an example of framescript - https://github.com/Noitidart/Full-Stop

Comment: I had assumed that framescripts and content-scripts are the same, but that is apparently wrong-ish? *sigh*
I will look into framescripts now, hopefully it works. Thank you :)

Comment: Its very different, to see how to use content script from framescript see this addon - https://github.com/Noitidart/Tweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to using drawWindow() was indeed to use framescripts as Noitidart suggested in the comments. The framescript I use for the screenshots looks like this:

```js
addMessageListener("fs/make_screenshot_from_rectangle", makeScreenshot);

function makeScreenshot(payload) {
    var rectangle = payload.data;
    var startX = rectangle.startX || 0;
    var startY = rectangle.startY || 0;
    var width = rectangle.width || content.innerWidth;
    var height = rectangle.height || content.innerHeight;
    // Create canvas to draw window unto
    var canvas = content.document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    // Create context for drawing, draw the old window unto the canvas
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawWindow(content, startX, startY, width, height, "rgb(255,255,255)");
    // Save context as png
    var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    sendAsyncMessage("got-screenshot", image);
}
```

And it is called from a chrome-script with the following function:

```js
function (rectangle) {
    var tab = require("sdk/tabs").activeTab;
    var xulTab = require("sdk/view/core").viewFor(tab);
    var xulBrowser = require("sdk/tabs/utils").getBrowserForTab(xulTab);

    var browserMM = xulBrowser.messageManager;
    if ( /* framescript not yet attached to tab */ ) {
        browserMM.loadFrameScript(require("sdk/self").data.url("content-scripts/frame-script.js"), false);
        ... // do something to remember that there is a framescript attached to the tab
        browserMM.addMessageListener("got-screenshot", function (payload) {
            ... // handle the screenshot
        });
    }
    browserMM.sendAsyncMessage('fs/make_screenshot_from_rectangle', rectangle);
}
```

Relevant reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Multiprocess_Firefox_and_the_SDK
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Message_Manager/Message_manager_overview#Browser_messa

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing! This is some fantastic work!